# Single default value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a table that'll have a single bit not null column `IsDefault`. I need to write a constraint that'll make sure there'll be only one default value per `UserId` (field in the same table).
I can't use unique constraint on this because it is possible to have many non-default values.

What is the best approach to do this using MS SQL Server 2008?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I see is a check constraint with a UDF (User Defined function).

Look at here, for example.
http://sqljourney.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/check-constraint-with-user-defined-function-in-sql-server/

Untested example

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckDefaultUnicity(@UserId int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) FROM <your table> where UserId = @UserId and <columnwithDefault> = 1-- or whatever is your default value
   RETURN @retval 
END;
GO
```

and alter your table

```
ALTER TABLE <yourTable> 
ADD CONSTRAINT Ck_UniqueDefaultForUser 
CHECK (dbo.CheckDefaultUnicity(UserId) <2)
```

Comment: +1 but I recommend always using `dbo.` prefix when creating / referencing UDFs...

Answer (score 1):

Another relatively simple option is to use a `CLUSTERED INDEXED VIEW`. The gist of this is to

- Select all `UserID`'s from your table where `IsDefault=1` in a view.
- Add a unique index on `UserID`

**Clustered indexed view**

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VIEW_Users_IsDefault WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
  SELECT  UserID, IsDefault
  FROM    dbo.Users
  WHERE   IsDefault = 1
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_VIEW_USERS_ISDEFAULT 
  ON dbo.VIEW_Users_IsDefault (UserID)
GO
```

**Test script**

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users (UserID INT, IsDefault BIT)
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.VIEW_Users_IsDefault WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
  SELECT  UserID, IsDefault
  FROM    dbo.Users
  WHERE   IsDefault = 1
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_VIEW_USERS_ISDEFAULT ON dbo.VIEW_Users_IsDefault (UserID)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES (1, 0)
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES (1, 1)  -- Fails because of clustered index

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 1):

A Check Constraint would definitely work, however it's not good a design choice in my opinion.  The reason being that your UDF for the constraint would be something like

```
SELECT @Count = COUNT(UserId) 
FROM   User
WHERE  IsDefault = 1
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(UserId) > 1

IF @Count > 0 
  ....'FAIL
```

As this touches 2 columns it would thus need to be a Table level constraint and the more records you have the slower a Insert/Update/Delete will take.

A better option would be to only allow access to that table via Stored Procedure, so before an insert/update you could run a very quick

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM User where UserId = @UserId and IsDefault = 1)
```

before your inserts/updates/deletes

I can however appreciate that you may be using an ORM and might not want to have Stored Procs in your system so you could change the design of your table to the below.  This assumes that

tblUser: UserId, FirstName, Suraname, etc

tblUserDefault: *UserId* (Unique Constraint)

I'm not sure what IsDefault represents in your system so I'm assuming in the above that Users are either default or not. Anybody you can use that as a reference. It allows you to enforce the constraint without using USP's or horrid tablewide check constraints (or triggers) and would be mappable in any decent ORM

Comment: IsDefault is actually not related to user its about Id Cards, there's one-to-many relation between user and a card, but a user can only have one default card. About access to data actually our application uses a DB login that only has rights to access via procedures, so that's in place, but if an sysadmin logs in the db he could do an insert/update and break the application. So I'd prefer data integrity here.

Comment: In that case you could have a table, tblDefaultIdCard: FK_UserId, FK_CardId with a Unique Key on FK_UserId and a UniqueKey on FK_CardId

Answer (score 0):

What about `CHECK Constraints`. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD CONSTRAINT IsDefaultChecked CHECK (IsDefault = T );
```

Comment: Check constraint was my first idea too, but I didn't know how to implement it with multiple possible non-default values and only one default. Could you give me a bit more information on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a trigger in this case.  When the user is changing their default, the trigger could automatically flip the current default for the current user to false.

Basically, use an AFTER insert/update trigger to set the IsDefault column to 0 for any user in the insert/update where the IsDefault value is being set to 1.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_default
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS

  if(exists(select * from inserted where IsDefault = 1)
  begin

      update dbo.MyTable
        set IsDefault = 0
      from inserted i
      join dbo.MyTable t on i.userid = t.userid
      where i.IsDefault = 1
        and i.TheValue != t.TheValue

  end
```

Comment: SQL Server has INSTEAD OF triggers, not BEFORE triggers. You still need to proceed with writing the insert / update in this case.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks!  Updated to AFTER trigger.  BEFORE would have been much easier though :)

Comment: BEFORE would be much easier. Please vote and comment here: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/285655/triggers-before-insert-and-row-level

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with any of the answers so far suggesting `CHECK CONSTRAINTS` and `TRIGGERS` however, it seems like a bit of a backwards solution to me.

I can only assume `UserID` in your table is a foreign key to a `User` table, so why not add a column to your User table to store the default CardID, rather than marking one as default? This makes it impossible for a user to have multiple default CardIDs without costly triggers/constraints. If you make the column non nullable then it is also impossible for a user not to have a default CardID if you so wish.

Comment: I think it would need to be `DefaultCardId` in the user table. I don't really like this because when you do this for another table, you have to add another column to the user table... and then the logic would have to be different in the case where it's not default but something else where multiple options are possible, but say a max of 3 - `FavoriteColor1`, `FavoriteColor2`, `FavoriteColor3`?

Comment: Your point does seem a bit odd, you seem to be implying that every problem has to be solved in the same way once a precedent has been set! Although, where there is a max of 3 I would still be inclined to add 3 columns. Although I fear we could be entering into an EAV vs relational model debate, which has been done a million times before! I just think that performing checks upon every write will be less efficient than adding a column to a table. I am willing to be proved wrong though.

Comment: It's not just about efficiency. Consistency has some merit too. Anyway, I said "I don't really like this," which is just an opinion. Neither of us is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While I think the trigger and constraint solutions are better, if you control insert/update via stored procedure a much simpler approach would be to just update the conflicting rows first (assuming the new default always wins):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UserWhateverTable_<action>
  @UserID INT,
  @CardID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.UserWhatever 
      SET IsDefault = 0 
      WHERE UserID = @UserID
        AND CardID = @CardID
        AND IsDefault = 1;

    -- insert or update here
END
GO
```

In fact it might not be a bad idea to do this (so the business logic is 100% clear in your DML procedures) in addition to guarding it with a trigger or a constraint (to catch cases where updates are made outside of your procedures).